# Why Jsoup cannot select td element?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have made little test (with Jsoup 1.6.1):

```
String s = "" +Jsoup.parse("<td></td>").select("td").size();
System.out.println("Selected elements count : " + s);
```

It outputs:

```
Selected elements count : 0
```

But it should return 1, because I have parsed html with td element. What is wrong with my code or is there bug in Jsoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jsoup 1.6.2 allows to parse with different parser and simple XML parser is provided. With following code I could solve my problem. You can later parse your fragment with HTML parse, to get valid HTML.

```
// Jsoup 1.6.2
String s = "" + Jsoup.parse("<td></td>", "", Parser.xmlParser()).select("td").size();
System.out.println("Selected elements count : " + s);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) is a [HTML5 compliant](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) parser and you feeded it with invalid HTML. A `<td>` has to go inside at least a `<table>`.

```
int size = Jsoup.parse("<table><td></td></table>").select("td").size();
System.out.println("Selected elements count : " + size);
```

Comment: Well why it parses <table><tr><td></td></tr></table>, if it doesn't contain body etc required elements? I think it should be able to parse these elements, because most of time you want to handle fragments, that's whole point in getting element HTML.

Comment: Jsoup parses it implicitly relative to `<body>` when the fragment doesn't contain `<html><head><body>`. A `<td>` can't be relative to a `<body>`, but only to `<table>`.

Comment: In fact, <body>, <head> and <html> tags are _not_ required tags according to html spec.  But <td> does need to be inside a <table>.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.3 - reference for my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
String url = "http://foobar.com";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements td = doc.select("td");
```