# Jsoup :has() selector not working as expected

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, css-selectors, jsoup

I am trying to parse a HTML table containing multiple cells with the following structure:

```html
<td id="topic1234">
    <a name='1234'></a>
    <b><a href='/url'>Title</a><b>
    <span class='s'>Details</span>
</td>
<td id="topic2345">
    <a name='2345'></a>
    <b><a href='/url'>Title</a><b>
    <span class='s'>Details</span>
</td>
...
```

The 'id' attribute, 'a' element with a 'href' attribute, and 'span' element are the important details, and the two elements are directly nested.
I tried using

```
select("[id^=topic]"
          + ":has(> b > a[href])"
          + ":has(> span.s)")
```

but the resulting list is empty. It works when I change it to:

```
select("td[id^=topic]"
          + ":has(td > b > a[href])"
          + ":has(td > span.s)")
```

but I don't want the selector to depend on the fact that the root element is a 'td', and judging by the documentation, the former should also work. The following didn't work either:

```
select("[id^=topic]"
          + ":has(:root > b > a[href])"
          + ":has(:root > span.s)")
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Using Jsoup 1.8.3 by the way.

Comment: `:root` doesn't work because it always refers to the document root regardless of the scope of the selector - in HTML, this is typically <html>. In selectors-4, this would normally be represented by `:scope` - I doubt it works in jsoup, though...

Comment: Maybe `:has(> b >...)` doesn't work because jsoup doesn't support relative selectors either, in which case, you might have to resort to selecting the `[id^=...]` element and inspecting its children separately. The closest you can get with a selector in that case would be `:has(b >...)`, but as I'm sure you are aware it doesn't mean quite the same thing.

Comment: How is your full HTML structured? I mean, do the `<td>` elements live inside a `<table>` tag? I am asking you this because according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985791/why-jsoup-cannot-select-td-element), JSoup is not able to detect "lone" `td`s.

Comment: @user2340612: Well, considering the first sentence of the question I'd assume that the cells do in fact live in a table.

Comment: @BoltClock whops, I totally missed that sentence!

Comment: @user2340612: Never hurts to be explicit either way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector in `:has(selector)` includes the parent element. I don't think that `>b` is a valid selector in JSoup, but `*>b` should be okay and it allows any parent element. So this should work:

```
select("[id^=topic]"
      + ":has(* > b > a[href])"
      + ":has(* > span.s)")
```

**Edit1 in response of comment:**

To make it more likely that the selector of `:has(selector)` is a direct child of `[id^=topic]` you could also do this:

```
select("[id^=topic]"
      + ":has([id^=topic] > b > a[href])"
      + ":has([id^=topic] > span.s)")
```

This of course is still not a guarantee, since inner children of the parent may carry also an id that starts with `topic`.

**Edit2**

Similar to the [solution of user2340612](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35869477/2229229) you can make sure by splitting up the selector into two parts. First we match for all elements with ids starting with topic. Then we cycle over these and construct a new selector that includes the specific id. This will work as long as the ids of all elements are individual.

```
String html = "<table><tr><td id=\"topic1234\">" +
        "<a name='1234'></a>" +
        "<div><b><a href='/url'>Title</a></b></div>" +
        "<span class='s'>Details</span></td>\n" +
        "<td id=\"topic2345\">\n" +
        "    <a name='2345'></a>\n" +
        "    <b><a href='/url'>Title</a></b>\n" +
        "    <span class='s'>Details</span>\n" +
        "</td>"+
        "<td id=\"topic3456\">\n" +
        "    <div id=\"topic4567\"><a name='3456'></a>\n" +
        "    <b><a href='/url'>Title</a></b>\n" +
        "    <span class='s'>Details</span>\n" +
        "    </div>" +
        "</td></tr></table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements selected = doc.select("[id^=topic]");
for (Element elem : selected) {
  String idStr = elem.attr("id");
  Element el = elem.select(":has(#"+idStr+" > b > a[href]):has(#"+idStr+" > span.s)").first();
  if (el != null){
      System.out.println("found matching element: "+el);
  }
  if (el != null){
      System.out.println("does not really match: "+el);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that `:has(* > b)` is equivalent to `:has(b)`, which will match even if the `b` isn't a child of the element with the id, but a child of some other element within it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your second option works just fine for me since the `topic` IDs are not nested.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it's not possible to write a single selector for what you need, since JSoup does not support syntax like `:has(> tag)`.

I think, however, that you can split your selector in multiple parts:

```
String html = "<table><td id=\"topic1234\">" +
                  "<a name='1234'></a>" +
                  "<div><b><a href='/url'>Title</a></b></div>" +
                  "<span class='s'>Details</span></td>\n" +
                  "<td id=\"topic2345\">\n" +
                  "    <a name='2345'></a>\n" +
                  "    <b><a href='/url'>Title</a></b>\n" +
                  "    <span class='s'>Details</span>\n" +
                  "</td></table>"

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements selected = doc.select("[id^=topic]");
for (Element elem : selected) {
    // Check if "b > a[href]" is a direct child of "td"
    if (elem.select(":root > b > a[href]").size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Found: "+elem);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not found:"+elem);
    }
}
```

i.e. the html code is the following:

```html
<table>
    <td id="topic1234">
        <a name="1234"></a>
        <div>
            <b><a href="/url">Title</a></b>
        </div>
    <span class="s">Details</span></td>
    <!-- second line -->    
    <td id="topic2345">
        <a name="2345"></a>
        <b><a href="/url">Title</a></b>
        <span class="s">Details</span>
    </td>
</table>
```

Which returns:

```
Not found:<td id="topic1234"><a name="1234"></a>
 <div>
  <b><a href="/url">Title</a></b>
 </div><span class="s">Details</span></td>
Found: <td id="topic2345"> <a name="2345"></a> <b><a href="/url">Title</a></b> <span class="s">Details</span> </td>
```

Obviously the same could be applied for the second condition (i.e. `span.s`)

Note that in this case `:root` selector works because the root element for `elem` is `td` and not `table`